# Glusterfs Brick size

Tags: amazon-ec2, filesystems, storage, glusterfs, xfs

I am adding a physical disk of 8GB for glusterfs storage 
physical drive-xvdf, partition-xvdf1

```
[root@ip-10-xx-x-xx replicated1]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0   8G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0   8G  0 part /data/brick1
```

Install xfs and format the partition

```
mkfs.xfs -i size=512 /dev/sdf1
```

Now,mount the directory data/brick1 to the newly created partition

```
echo "/dev/sdf1 /data/brick1 xfs defaults 1 2" >> /etc/fstab
mount -a && mount


[root@ip-10-xx-x-xx replicated1]# gluster volume status test-volume detail
Status of volume: rep-volume

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick                : Brick 10.xx.x.xx:/data/brick1/replicated1
Port                 : 49154
Online               : Y
Pid                  : 2103
File System          : xfs
Device               : /dev/xvdf1
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
Inode Size           : 512
Disk Space Free      : 8.0GB
Total Disk Space     : 8.0GB
Inode Count          : 4193792
Free Inodes          : 4193697
```

There is also another option such as gluster volume status test-volume mem. 
My question is what is my brick size here ?

Also, Can i have multiple bricks in a single partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my question is what is my brick size here ?

8 GB

> Also, Can i have multiple bricks in a single partition?

You could for testing purposes but usually there is a 1:1 mapping between bricks and their mount points.